# YouTube upload form entries with PHP/XML

Tags: php, curl, youtube

I have a script for YouTube which allows me or anyone else to use on a site to upload videos directly to a YouTube account.

The problem is only the video is uploaded with no video information such as title & description I want the person who is uploading the video to have the options of filling in a form which will then result in the title & description on YouTube.

The script can be seen at the bottom. What I want is for a form to be in place which is something like the following:

Video Title: Cat Drives Car

Video By: MrShoez

Video Description: Watch this video of a cat driving a car.

And the title output would be something as "Cat Drives Car by MrShoez"

Along with the description displaying: This video was submitted on DATE HERE by MrShoez. "Watch this video of a cat driving a car."

```
 *

<?php
        $youtube_email = "email@address.com"; // Change this to your youtube sign in email.
        $youtube_password = "password"; // Change this to your youtube sign in password.

        $postdata = "Email=".$youtube_email."&Passwd=".$youtube_password."&service=youtube&source=Example";
        $curl = curl_init("https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        list($auth, $youtubeuser) = explode("\n", $response);
        list($authlabel, $authvalue) = array_map("trim", explode("=", $auth));
        list($youtubeuserlabel, $youtubeuservalue) = array_map("trim", explode("=", $youtubeuser));



        $youtube_video_title = "VIDEO TITLE";  // This is the uploading video name.
        $youtube_video_description = "VIDEO DESCRIPTION"; // This is the uploading video description.
        $youtube_video_category = "CATEGORY"; // This is the uploading video category.
        $youtube_video_keywords = "tags, tags, tags, tags"; // This is the uploading video keywords.

        $data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
                    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
                      xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
                      xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
                       <media:group>
                        <yt:private/>
                        <media:title type="plain">'.$youtube_video_title.'</media:title>
                        <media:description type="plain">'.$youtube_video_description.'</media:description>
                        <media:category
                          scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">'.$youtube_video_category.'</media:category>
                        <media:keywords>'.$youtube_video_keywords.'</media:keywords>
                      </media:group>
                    </entry>';

        $key = "UNIQUEKEY HERE"; // Get your key here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/.

        $headers = array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$authvalue,
                         "GData-Version: 2",
                         "X-GData-Key: key=".$key,
                         "Content-length: ".strlen($data),
                         "Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8");

        $curl = curl_init("http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        $response = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($curl));
        curl_close($curl);
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function checkForFile() {
            if (document.getElementById('file').value) {
              return true;
            }
            document.getElementById('errMsg').style.display = '';
            return false;
          }
        </script>

         <?php
        $nexturl = "http://website.com/directurl"; // This parameter specifies the URL to which YouTube will redirect the user's browser when the user uploads his video file.
        ?>


        <form action="<?php echo($response->url); ?>?nexturl=<?php echo(urlencode($nexturl)); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkForFile();">


          <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>


          <div id="errMsg" style="display:none;color:red">
            You need to specify a file.
          </div>
           <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo($response->token); ?>"/>
          <input type="submit" value="go" />



        </form>
        </php>
```

*